# iOS, CoreText and Unicode

Tags: xml, ios, unicode, core-text

I was wondering how should I encode a text to be displayed using CoreText. For information, CoreText provides native Unicode support.

But, if I've my source text, for example in a XML file, how should I have to encode it to be properly rendered?

```
<node>Text with Unicode àccented charactèrs would cause XML formatting errors!</node>
```

I was also thinking using NSString+HTML that provides method like this (don't remember the exact method name, it's just a sample):

```
[string stringByDecodingHtmlEntities]
```

So what would you suggest?

Thanks,
Simone.

Comment: If you store your strings in XML, then you should be able to simply write any Unicode characters in there without any escaping (except for `<` and `&`). As long as you edit the XML with a sane editor that handles the encoding correctly, that should just work.

Answer (score 1):

You should use UTF-8. As this is the default encoding on Max OS X and iOS, as well for XML, this should *just work*, as Joachim said.

If you want to be really sure, make sure that your editor is configured to write UTF-8, and specify the encoding in an XML declaration at the beginning of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```